# Sorting bibliography and modifying apa-style of BibLaTeX properly

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, bibliographystyle

I worked my way through the biblatex and apastyle documentation, but couldn't find a way to solve my problems. Maybe one of you can help me.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage[style=apa, sorting=none,doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literature.bib}
\begin{document}
text with \cite{Example.2002} or \footcite{Example.2003}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As shown above, I am using biblatex and the `\footcite` or `\cite` commands for my references. While using the apastyle in my preamble two main problems arise:

1. Without `sorting=none` the bibliography remains empty. But I want an alphabetic order for which I would need to apply the `nyt`-option but then the bibliography is not attached.
2. I want to put the year for both citations commands into parentheses. I tried to find a way through the `authoryear`-style which leads to broken references and even more problems. Is there a possibility to apply the parentheses in my example?

I read a lot of similar threads and I know that there are other approaches but I would to prefer to change as little as possible because it took a long time to get the current version in an acceptable form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welecome to TeX.se. The the `\bibliographystyle` command isn't used with `biblatex` and is ignored. You definitely shouldn't be using `sorting=none` with the `apa` style. The `apa` style implements the exact APA 7th edition style, and is not really designed to be modified. You should be using `\textcite` not `\cite` for in text citations. For your footnotes, it would be simpler just to use `\footnote{\textcite{...}}` instead of `\footcite`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now the bibliography-sorting is exactly as wished.
Regarding the `\footnote{\textcite{...}}`-command: is it possible to add prefixes like "See" and "page X". Till now I used `\footcite[See][P. 1]{Example.2014}`.

Comment: The prenote with `\textcite` isn't really useful, since it puts it inside the parentheses.  The postnote can be used, and it will appear (as per APA format) as Author (year, pg).

Comment: Ok, but that is something I can live with. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll convert these comments into an answer to that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apa` style for `biblatex` implements an exact version of the APA 7th edition style, and is not really designed to be modified. You certainly should not be using `sorting=none` with it.  Furthermore, the `\bibliographystyle` command is not used will `biblatex` and will be ignored. To use in-text citations with `apa` you should use the `\textcite` command. This will give you Author (Year) citations. Instead of using `\footcite` you can instead use `\footnote{\textcite{...}}` which will yield the same format inside footnotes.

When using an author/year scheme, the prenote is not very useful, since it appears inside the parenthesized year. The postnote can be used, and in the APA style, will appear with a comma after the year. Note that for the postnote, you should just provide a page number or a page range, and the style will add the `p.` or `pp.` automatically.

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[style=apa, doi=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
See \textcite[529-531]{bertram} or\footnote{\textcite[579]{glashow}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: text output]
[image: footnote output]
[image: bibliography output]